# continuity of a two variable function at $(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$f(x,y)=\frac{2(x^3+y^3)}{x^2+2y}$$

Show that $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$ when it is given that $f(x,y)=0$ at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Normally substituting $y=mx^n$ works.. not in this case

Comment: what do you mean when you say "not in this case"

Comment: in here it is not working

Comment: substituting it doesn't reduce it to the form \frac{1+m^p}{A+m^q} which would have done the job

Comment: Ok... /i have just now checked.. They does not help much ..how about taking polar coordinates?? $x=\cos \theta$ and $y=\sin \theta$?

Comment: What is $$f\left(x,-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$$ for $x\neq 0$?

Comment: @ praphulla .. I am not sure how $cos\theta$, sin$\theta$ helps??

Comment: @ daniel .. Not defined at $(x,-\frac{x^2}{2})$.. Can i get something like $y=mx^n$ where the whole limit will depend upon $m$??

Comment: @Prayagdeep My point is that the denominator vanishes there, but the numerator doesn't. So if you approach the origin along a curve sufficiently close to that, you can obtain the limits $\pm \infty$.

Comment: @ daniel .. thank you.. got it